# Need help in stored procedure for select query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch data on the basis of first name and last name. I have two DB replica of one another except for few extra data in one DB. Below is the stored procedure for the same. The problem is that I want data fetched first part of the(ie is if I search for ar it should show names starting with ar like arron but not in the middle like Sharon). The query is working fine with one db & not with the other one.

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEARCH]
(
@firstName nvarchar(50),
@lastName nvarchar(50),
@state nvarchar(50),
@county nvarchar(50),
@searchspan nvarchar(5)
)
AS

BEGIN 
declare @queryString nvarchar(max)
declare @countyId nvarchar(50)
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 

Create table #temp1(
county nvarchar(50) NULL,
ID nvarchar(50) NULL,
name nvarchar(200) NULL,
state nvarchar(50) NULL,
FirstName nvarchar(50) NULL,
LastName nvarchar(50) NULL,
county nvarchar(50) NULL,
)
set @queryString = 'insert into #temp1 select  distinct a.Source as county, a.ID as ID, a.FirstName +'' ''+ a.LastName as name, ''' +
 @state +''' as state,a.FirstName,a.LastName,b.county, from Person a, CountySite b where 1=1 and a.Source=b.sourcecounty '

 if(@searchspan<>'')
 BEGIN
 set @queryString = @queryString  = 1'
 END
  EXECUTE  sp_executesql  @queryString
  set @queryString ='select county, ID, name, state,col_FirstName,col_LastName,col_county, from #temp1 where 1=1 '
 if(@firstName <> '')
BEGIN 
 set @queryString = @queryString+ ' and UPPER(col_FirstName) like ''' +@firstName +'%'''
END
if(@lastName <> '')
BEGIN 
 set @queryString = @queryString + ' and UPPER(col_LastName) like ''' +@lastName +'%'''
drop table #temp1
END
```

Comment: When you say not working do you mean it throws an error or doesn't return the results expected?

Comment: @Fred: It doesn't return value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSQL is not case-sensitive and you don't need to use UPPER

Also change your query to

```
set @queryString = @queryString + ' and col_LastName like @lastName +'%'
```

Try this

```
SET @queryString = @queryString + ' AND col_LastName  LIKE '''+@lastName +'%'''
```

Comment: Why do you say that TSQL is not case-sensitive? It is if the database has a case-sensitive collation.

Comment: @user1374181 Something is wrong someewhere. I have tested that code. It won't work if @LastName is NULL. do `ISNULL(@lastName,'')`

Comment: @codingbiz: thats the problem... something is wrong with the code but dont know what it is...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have profiler so that you can see the query that is being executed on the second DB? Just to ensure that it's the same. Just for grins you may want to try dropping and re-executing the SP on the DB's.

Comment: Have done it buddy... I get results when my query is: set @queryString = @queryString+ ' and UPPER(col_FirstName) like ''%' +@firstName +'%'''